Invalid assumptions in symbolic inequality simplification
I want to determine whether the following inequality holds and obtain True or False as a result. It's easy to determine manually that the result is True, but the MMA code fails to reach this conclusion because it does not take into account the assumption x ≥ positiveRoot. How can I fix the code? Thanks in advance!
ClearAll["Global`*"];
F[x_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, 
   n_] := (\[Alpha] x^(2 n + 1))/(2 n + 1) - \[Alpha] \[Beta] x;

positiveRoot = ((1 + 2 n) \[Beta])^((1/2)/n);

FPrime[x_] := D[F[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], n], x];

(*Check if F'[x] is greater than 0 when x>=positiveRoot*)
monotonicityTest = 
 FullSimplify[
  FPrime[x] > 0, {x >= positiveRoot, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, 
   n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]

Output:
x^(2 n) > \[Beta]


Log may be used to convert (some) exponential equations to polynomial ones. But what a pain in this case:
assum = {x >= positiveRoot, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, 
   n \[Element] PositiveIntegers,
   Log /@ (x >= positiveRoot) // PowerExpand,
   1 + 2 n > 1, Log /@ (1 + 2 n > 1)};
FullSimplify[
 fPrime[x] > 0 // Simplify // Map@Log // PowerExpand //
  Inactivate[#, Log] &
 , assum // Inactivate[#, Log] &
 ] (*//Activate*)

(*  True  *)

Needed some additional assumptions for FullSimplify, and I had to inactivate Log so that Log[x] etc. would be treated as variables. You can also replace the logs with actual variables; for instance, {Log[x] -> lx, Log[1 + 2 n] -> lodd}.

Thank you very much. This is part of my work on verifying the existence and uniqueness of a stable limit cycle in the Lienard differential equation. I didn't expect to encounter so many difficulties in verifying the uniqueness of the limit cycle for a symbolic ODE that isn’t very complex. At this point, it also seems challenging to write a general code for this purpose.
